# Using classes (and traits) within a Symfony 2 application and avoiding IDE warnings

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, traits

I am interested to know what the correct approach is to using/requiring classes within a Symfony 2 application.

At the moment the application follows this sort of structure:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Entity\Course;
use AppBundle\Services\Course\AddOns;
use AppBundle\Services\Course\AddOns\AddOnBase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Processor
{
    use AppBundle\Traits\LoggerTrait;

    use AppBundle\Traits\ReportManagerTrait;
```

Previously the `use` of the traits were like `use \AppBundle\Traits\LoggerTrait;` (note the leading backslash) and PhpStorm (and likely other IDEs) were complaing, or at least warning, that the traits could not be found. Seemingly a workaround for this was to include the entire bundle with `use AppBundle`, however I fear this may have performance issues and to the eye it doesn't look correct.

What are the coding standards and recommendations within a SF2 application for this?

Comment: Are you having any specific problems? The `use` statements on the specific classes are enough, this has always worked for me. You might also want to take a look at the [Symfony plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=idea) which works miracles for your Symfony project in terms of autocompletion and service recognition.

Comment: There won't be any performance issue.  Normally you would have use AppBundle\Traits\LoggerTrait; at the top of your file and then use LoggerTrait; in your class.